# Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot does not swap the physical site only the application settings

Tags: powershell, azure, swap

I have been running the following command via powershell for AZURE but all that gets swapped are the application settings:

```
Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName 'myresourcegroup' -Name 'mywebsitename' -SourceSlotName "staging" -DestinationSlotName "production"  -confirm -verbose
```

The same thing happens when I run this command:

```
Switch-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName 'myresourcegroup' -Name 'mywebsitename' -SourceSlotName "staging" -DestinationSlotName "production" -SwapWithPreviewAction CompleteSlotSwap -confirm -verbose
```

I cannot use Switch-AzureWebsite as I cannot set a default subscription with my permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Login-AzureRMAccount the only way I found to switch slots is as follows:

$ParametersObject = @{targetSlot = "production"}
$RGN = 'resource-group-name-'

Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $RGN -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName website-name/staging -Action slotsswap -Parameters $ParametersObject -Verbose -force

This was hard to find, in part because many examples required you to set your Azure default subscription prior to executing Switch-AzureWebsite and the other switch only moved the configuration elements over. I am curious if anyone has a clever way to discover power shell commands or ARM template commands aside from the ones generated for deployments on Azure. Ideally, I could perform an action on Azure an then see same thing scripted as PowerShell.

REF: [Microsoft Docs Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing)